Not able to connect SSH remote host with visual studio code
I was using the VS code to work on a project with remote host for a while. However, last Friday I could not connect to the remote host by either terminal nor vs code as usual. And after long debugging I realized that the storage where I installed my vscode extension is full and I was advised to remove the whole ./vscode folder by school IT and advise me not to install on Home folder since there is limited space. I did that and then I was able to connect to ssh with terminal again. (Now I have sufficient space in my home folder)
Then the problem started, no matter how hard I tried, I cannot reconnect using vs code. It shows : Could not establish connection to..." After I pass the authentication part, it would show and judging by the fact that I successfully connected to the Genuis page and this line in the log "Creating the server install dir failed...", I think I am not able to reinstall the extension on my ssh.
[20:46:56.489] Log Level: 2
[20:46:56.497] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be", attempt 1
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.path": ssh vsc35116@login.hpc.kuleuven.be
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.configFile": /Users/Joanna/.ssh/config
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[20:46:56.498] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[20:46:56.499] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[20:46:56.501] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[20:46:56.501] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[20:46:56.501] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true
[20:46:56.501] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[20:46:56.501] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[20:46:56.504] VS Code version: 1.89.1
[20:46:56.504] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.110.1
[20:46:56.504] darwin arm64
[20:46:56.505] SSH Resolver called for host: login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be
[20:46:56.506] Setting up SSH remote "login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be"
[20:46:56.508] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/w_/b_dtrt656552kywhgk24kp0c0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-cb0c34ab-install.lock
[20:46:56.509] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/Joanna/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cb0c34ab-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685-0.110.1-es/data.json
[20:46:56.510] Using commit id "dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685" and quality "stable" for server
[20:46:56.513] Install and start server if needed
[20:46:56.515] Checking ssh with "ssh vsc35116@login.hpc.kuleuven.be -V"
[20:46:56.523] Got error from ssh: spawn ssh vsc35116@login.hpc.kuleuven.be ENOENT
[20:46:56.523] The specified path ssh vsc35116@login.hpc.kuleuven.be is not a valid SSH binary
[20:46:56.523] PATH: /Users/Joanna/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/Joanna/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin
[20:46:56.523] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[20:46:56.535] > OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[20:46:56.537] Using SSH config file "/Users/Joanna/.ssh/config"
[20:46:56.538] askpass server listening on /var/folders/w_/b_dtrt656552kywhgk24kp0c0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8afc7c3f5d728484121b24d5dccf670e5b6180f2.sock
[20:46:56.539] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/w_/b_dtrt656552kywhgk24kp0c0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-784ffa7686b9c8789e1fde5ea6e2b145f1437aae.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","58566","-o","ConnectTimeout=30","-F","/Users/Joanna/.ssh/config","login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/Joanna/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cb0c34ab-dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685-0.110.1-es/data.json"}
[20:46:56.539] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.iCRXcskQmA/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ljAvRAT7Ji/org.xquartz:0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/w_/b_dtrt656552kywhgk24kp0c0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8afc7c3f5d728484121b24d5dccf670e5b6180f2.sock"}
[20:46:56.540] Spawned 77557
[20:46:56.701] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 58566 -o ConnectTimeout=30 -F /Users/Joanna/.ssh/config login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be
[20:46:56.704] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=77566
[20:46:56.708] stderr> OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[20:46:56.948] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:BESJCI8DTyYMdM3dWdKzX8GFDo4PpZJCfAU1t+IpKWo
[20:46:57.405] stderr> Logging in as vsc35116 from [2a02:1808:204:6032:581a:80d:e0e4:707d]:58567.
[20:46:57.405] stderr> Please open https://firewall.hpc.kuleuven.be/yij7UBSQRbquIoSkdth to complete logon.
[20:47:13.464] stderr> Authenticated to login-genius.hpc.kuleuven.be ([2a02:2c40:0:2430::1028]:22) using "keyboard-interactive".
[20:47:13.573] >   _____               _
>  |  __ \             (_)
>  | |  \/  ___  _ __   _  _   _  ___
>  | | __  / _ \| '_ \ | || | | |/ __|
>  | |_\ \|  __/| | | || || |_| |\__ \
>   \____/ \___||_| |_||_| \__,_||___/
> 
> Informatie over deze server (FQDN): tier2-p-login-1.genius.hpc.kuleuven.be
>  * cluster: genius
>  * role: login
>  * hardware: ProLiant DL380 Gen10 (x86_64)
>  * os: Rocky 8.9
>  * kernel: 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64
>  * architecture: skylake
>  * architecture-suffix: 
> 
> Welcome to the KU Leuven/UHasselt Tier-2 cluster!
> Documentation is available on https://docs.vscentrum.be
> 
> Queue state at 2024-05-14 20:40:02
> 
> For CPU partitions, the occupation refers to nodes.
> For GPU partitions, the occupation refers to single GPUs.
> 
> [38;2;123;146;70m[48;2;123;146;70m             Free nodes/GPUs
> [38;2;211;160;77m[48;2;211;160;77m             Partially free nodes
> [38;2;165;60;35m[48;2;165;60;35m             Unavailable nodes/GPUs
> genius:
>   batch                [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m9 [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m 21  [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                         196                           Pending jobs: 178
> 
>   bigmem               [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m        2        [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                     5                       Pending jobs:   6
> 
>   gpu_p100             [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m   8   [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                         56                            Pending jobs:   4
> 
>   gpu_v100             [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m            7             [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                9                   Pending jobs:  17
> 
> wice:
>   batch_icelake        [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m       50        [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                    120                      Pending jobs:  11
> 
>   batch_sapphirerapids [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m2[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m 5  [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                          61                             Pending jobs:   3
> 
>   bigmem               [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m     1      [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                       4                          Pending jobs:   2
> 
>   hugemem              [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                             1                                Pending jobs:   1
> 
>   gpu_a100             [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                             16                               Pending jobs:  43
> 
>   gpu_h100             [38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;123;146;70m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;211;160;77m[38;2;245;245;245m[48;2;165;60;35m                             16                               Pending jobs:  28
> 
> [38;2;211;160;77mAnnouncement: on May 20 the Skylake nodes of the Genius 'batch' partition
> [38;2;211;160;77mwill be taken out of regular operation and will be set up for teaching
> [38;2;211;160;77mpurposes and interactive work. All jobs sent to the Genius 'batch' partition
> [38;2;211;160;77mwill then run on Cascadelake nodes. Note that the other Genius partitions
> [38;2;211;160;77mwith Skylake nodes (bigmem, gpu_p100, superdome) will remain in operation.
[20:47:21.814] > ready: 9adad5d1899c
[20:47:21.874] > Linux 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 4 18:13:02 UTC 2024
[20:47:21.874] Platform: linux
[20:47:21.918] > /bin/bash
[20:47:21.919] Shell: bash
[20:47:21.919] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[20:47:21.984] > bash version:  4.4.20(1)-release
[20:47:22.029] > bash version:  4.4.20(1)-release
[20:47:22.053] > 9adad5d1899c: running
[20:47:22.064] > Creating the server install dir failed...
> 9adad5d1899c: start
> exitCode==34==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId====
> arch====
> vscodeArch====
> bitness====
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform====
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> serverStartTime====
> execServerToken==11a11aaa-a11a-1111-1a11-a11a11a111aa==
> 9adad5d1899c: end
[20:47:22.064] Received install output: 
exitCode==34==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId====
arch====
vscodeArch====
bitness====
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform====
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
serverStartTime====
execServerToken==11a11aaa-a11a-1111-1a11-a11a11a111aa==

[20:47:22.065] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[20:47:22.065] Terminating local server
[20:47:22.068] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:499181)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:496503)
    at e (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:557639)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:579548
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:583207)
    at async /Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:554344
    at async T (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:552395)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:553884)
    at async k (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:576765)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:580578)
    at async /Users/Joanna/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1/out/extension.js:2:846687
[20:47:22.073] ------ 

I tried uninstall reinstall the remote-ssh extension in vs code. tried remove /Home//.vscode-server ( not working since it is already deleted) and tried adding this line in the vscode settings (JSON) file.
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false

all fail. I also checked the config file and its path it all seems correct.
Please provide me some solution. I am so desperate.

Did you open https://firewall.hpc.kuleuven.be/yij7UBSQRbquIoSkdth to complete logon.?

yes I did. and it would be HPC Firewall
All set up!
You confirmed your identity as vsc35116 for your session. You may close this page.
but then showed the same error "Could not establish connection to..." on the visual studio code page
